# How to implement "Contact Us" view with a default Email destination address

Tags: ios, swift, email, networking

I am trying to build up a Contact Us View in one iOS project,  What I am trying to do is:

Put a `Text View`in a view controller, which will capture and save users' writing.
If users press send button, the view controller will send the Email or message to customer service. How to implement this or any SDK recommended?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**MFMailComposeViewController** is fully dedicated for this. it has built in what you are trying to make. So don't write code to take this hassle. Let Apple do it for you. :)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

place the uitextview on the storyboard, create an IBoutlet for your textview, and implement the uitextview delegate methods.

You can then use "shouldChangeTextInRange" to determine if the user has pressed enter.

You are going to need to hit a backend API to then send off the data through your mail server. if you don't have a backend server where you can code up a seamless email sending program, you can open up the mail app by using something like this:

```
let email = "foo@bar.com"
if let url = URL(string: "mailto:\(email)") {
     UIApplication.shared.open(url)
}
```